# Exchange and store values between different processes

Tags: c++, c, linux

My application needs to store and exchange some (one) values between different processes. Also behind a start of the application this value is needed (but not behind a system reboot). 
I can write and read this value in a file and synchronize the access. The file could lay in a ramfs. The solution would work but I have the feeling I use the wrong method.

Is there a better lightweight solution for this? Do I miss an straightforward approach? 
I was thinking about named pipes (mkfifo) but there needs always and active writer and reader?

Comment: You can use a shared memory with a semaphore..

Comment: you could also use memcached

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).  There are a number of methods for communicating between processes:

- Low-level shared memory
- Low-level named pipes
- Low-level sockets
- Remote procedure call mechanisms ([DCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model), [Corba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), [ONC RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call), etc.)
- REST api
- Distributed system frameworks

Which of these will work best for you depends on the complexity of the messages exchanged between processes, the complexity of the overall system, the need for portability, etc.

Shared memory is a very low-level approach and can feel the easiest solution "because it's just bytes in memory addressed by a pointer".  However, it's inherently low-level nature makes it also tedious to use.  There is no universally agreed upon C++ interface to these facilities, so you are left with low-level C style APIs for accessing and configuring shared memory between processes.  There are differences between platforms (POSIX does it one way; Windows does it another).

[Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) gives you a portable way to access shared memory mechanisms and aims to make [using them simpler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.making_ipc_easy).